# problem with asp.net redirection after login to admin page

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I built a simple site which has an open section and admin page, which you can get to, only after loging in.

I implemented the default asp .net login control.
The problem is, after successful login (the login page is called admin.aspx) I want to redirect to another page called groups.aspx (redirecting it by code - `Response.Redirect("AdminTools\\Groups.aspx")` ), but instead I get an error "The resource cannot be found.", which says that cannot find "login.aspx". The problem is I don't have a page called login.aspx in my site, and I can't manage to find the place where I can configure it.

Answer (score 2):

Always use `~` root operator.

```
Response.Redirect("~/AdminTools/Groups.aspx")
```

You can  configure your own login url by setting the `LoginUrl` in web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/mylogin.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```